# Problem with JavaFX and Apple M1 (Silicon) Chip and Intellij, Error : Loading library prism_es2 from resource failed and (mach-o file, need 'arm64e'))

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I have downloaded Intellij for Apple M1 (Silicon) Chip. And tried to create first project. I have used java jdk version 11.0.11 in project structure. But when I run the application the following error found :

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=53491:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/noorhossain/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/11.0.2/javafx-controls-11.0.2.jar:/Users/noorhossain/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/11.0.2/javafx-graphics-11.0.2.jar:/Users/noorhossain/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11.0.2/javafx-base-11.0.2.jar:/Users/noorhossain/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/11.0.2/javafx-fxml-11.0.2.jar -p /Users/noorhossain/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/11.0.2/javafx-graphics-11.0.2-mac.jar:/Users/noorhossain/IdeaProjects/demo2/target/classes:/Users/noorhossain/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11.0.2/javafx-base-11.0.2-mac.jar:/Users/noorhossain/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/11.0.2/javafx-fxml-11.0.2-mac.jar:/Users/noorhossain/.m2/repository/org/controlsfx/controlsfx/11.1.0/controlsfx-11.1.0.jar:/Users/noorhossain/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/11.0.2/javafx-controls-11.0.2-mac.jar -m com.example.demo2/com.example.demo2.HelloApplication
Loading library prism_es2 from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/noorhossain/.openjfx/cache/11.0.2/libprism_es2.dylib: dlopen(/Users/noorhossain/.openjfx/cache/11.0.2/libprism_es2.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/noorhossain/.openjfx/cache/11.0.2/libprism_es2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libprism_es2.dylib' (no such file)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/noorhossain/.openjfx/cache/11.0.2/libprism_es2.dylib: dlopen(/Users/noorhossain/.openjfx/cache/11.0.2/libprism_es2.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/noorhossain/.openjfx/cache/11.0.2/libprism_es2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libprism_es2.dylib' (no such file)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2627)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:768)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1837)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.installLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:205)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:185)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:157)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:52)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.lambda$static$0(ES2Pipeline.java:68)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:50)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Loading library prism_sw from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/noorhossain/.openjfx/cache/11.0.2/libprism_sw.dylib: dlopen(/Users/noorhossain/.openjfx/cache/11.0.2/libprism_sw.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/noorhossain/.openjfx/cache/11.0.2/libprism_sw.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libprism_sw.dylib' (no such file)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/noorhossain/.openjfx/cache/11.0.2/libprism_sw.dylib: dlopen(/Users/noorhossain/.openjfx/cache/11.0.2/libprism_sw.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/noorhossain/.openjfx/cache/11.0.2/libprism_sw.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libprism_sw.dylib' (no such file)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2627)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:768)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1837)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.installLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:205)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:185)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:157)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:52)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.lambda$static$0(SWPipeline.java:42)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.<clinit>(SWPipeline.java:41)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:222)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    ... 5 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here we can see that the first problem arises is `Loading library prism_es2 from resource failed` and some causes are : `(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))`

My maven dependencies are :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have searched some so questions, but cant actually figured out how to solve.

One more information, I did not use javaFx full sdk, Just add dependencies in maven to add the specific libraries from JavaFx.

Any idea How to solve this ?

Answer (score 4):

After struggle of 4 hours I am able to overcome the error by  upgrading the versions of the  dependencies  as follows :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I think, versions 11.0.2 of `javafx-controls` and `javafx-fxml` are not compatible for M1 silicon chip as it need `need 'arm64e'` as mentioned in the error, but its found in version `17.0.2`.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your setup but never mix versions for the various javafx modules. Maybe you should better use the openjfx maven plugin.