Mooc.fi Part 13 Graphic user interfaces - How to get JavaFX to work
I have not managed to get JavaFX to work and I am thus stuck on Part13 Graphic user interfaces My First Application (https://java-programming.mooc.fi/part-13/1-graphical-user-interfaces).
I have looked around a lot but I have not found anything that has made it work. First I downloaded JavaFX from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/ and followed https://ohjelmointi-20.mooc.fi/javafx-ohjeet but it didn't work and subsequently I have tried to follow what I have read in other threads. It seems like others have had problems with this before but it would be great if there were some instructions somewhere on how to configure things properly.
Some other threads in which it seems like people have asked about this issue: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjava/comments/nb2nrb/mooc_part_13_gui_cant_figure_out_how_to_connect/
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjava/comments/hl49y2/moocfi_part_13_and_openjfx/
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjava/comments/mrv4fq/javafx_sdk_or_jmods_for_moocfi/
Is anyone able to help out with this or give any leads on what I need to fix to make it work? Would be very appreciated from my side.
This is what the dependencies and plugins part of my POM file currently looks like:
`<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fi.helsinki.cs.tmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>edu-test-utils</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>testfx-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.15-alpha</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>testfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.15-alpha</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjfx-monocle</artifactId>
            <version>8u76-b04</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
   
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Djdk.net.URLClassPath.disableClassPathURLCheck=true</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>fi.helsinki.cs.tmc</groupId>
                <artifactId>runner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                    <launcher>launcher</launcher>
                    <mainClass>myFirstApplication.MyFirstApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>`

When I run the tests I get the error:
RuntimeException: No toolkit found
No toolkit found
com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.isFxApplicationThread(PlatformImpl.java:401)
javafx.application.Platform.isFxApplicationThread(Platform.java:182)
I have installed and configured Java FX, editing the POMs according to what I have seen other people use who have encountered the same issue (see links above).

Try using AdoptOpenJDK ver 11.
So head over to https://adoptopenjdk.net and download that Java version.
Then change your project structure to use AdoptOpenJDK. So head to Tools -> Java Platforms -> "Add Platform" (add newly downloaded files).
Then change Java version next to "Hammer icon".

Thank you for answering Piotr. I am already using the JDK 11 (https://adoptium.net/en-GB/temurin/releases/?os=mac&arch=aarch64&version=11). I have already done that. I think JDK 11 is required to take the course. However, the issue is with getting JavaFX and the GUI interface to work to work. Do you know how to fix that?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71630758/problem-with-javafx-and-apple-m1-silicon-chip-and-intellij-error-loading-li
